# How to correctly wait for Translation with react-i18next

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-i18next, react-suspense

I'm using react-18next to load translations throughout my react app. I have a problem making my app waiting for translations. This breaks our tests in Jenkins as they are searching for translated keys in many cases.

i18n.tsx:

```
i18n
.use(initReactI18next)
.init({
  resources, // set ressources to be used
  lng: "en", // set default language
  keySeparator: false, 
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false
  },
  react: {
    useSuspense: false,
  }
});
```

Note: I tried both using Suspense as well as not using suspense, the useSuspense Flag was matching the attempt (true/default for Suspense).

Attempt with ready:

```
const SiteLabel: React.FunctionComponent<ISiteLabelProps> = (props) => {
  const { t, ready } = useTranslation(undefined, {
    useSuspense: false
  });

  const getTo = (): string => {
    return "/" + props.module.toLowerCase();
  }

  const getLabel = (): string => {
    return props.module.toLowerCase() + ":GEN_PAGETITLE";
  }

  if(!ready)
    return (<div>Loading Content...</div>);

  return (
      <ConfirmLink
        content={t(getLabel())}
        dirty={props.dirty}
        setDirty={props.setDirty}
        className={Styles.label + " id-btn-riskshield"}
        to={getTo()}
        toState={null}
      />
  );
}

export default SiteLabel;
```

Attempt with Suspense:

```
const SiteLabel: React.FunctionComponent<ISiteLabelProps> = (props) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const getTo = (): string => {
    return "/" + props.module.toLowerCase();
  }

  const getLabel = (): string => {
    return props.module.toLowerCase() + ":GEN_PAGETITLE";
  }
    
  return (
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}
      <ConfirmLink
        content={t(getLabel())}
        dirty={props.dirty}
        setDirty={props.setDirty}
        className={Styles.label + " id-btn-riskshield"}
        to={getTo()}
        toState={null}
      />
      </Suspense>
  );
}

export default SiteLabel;
```

Neither version seems to work for me, I can see the translation key displayed for a brief moment. Do I need to go deeper until the point where the translation is actually written out instead of passed to the next prop or what is the Error I'm committing? I'm not using next.js for building/deployment. I would prefer a global solution right in app.tsx.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this could help you: https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#init

I use the callback to set a "all translations are really really loaded" state in my App component.

```
i18n
.use(initReactI18next)
.init(
  interpolation: { 
    escapeValue: false
  },
  fallbackLng: "en",
  react: {
    useSuspense: false,
  }, () => {
    setTranslationsLoaded(true);
  });
```

```
export const App = () => {
  const [translationsLoaded, setTranslationsLoaded] = useState(false)
  //...
  return (
    translationsLoaded ? <MyAppContent /> : <MySpinnerOrSomething />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try with `wait` option

`react: { wait: true, useSuspense: false }`

Comment: This is deprecated

Comment: @KevinJohnson useSuspense: false is still usable.